# Can i simplify this Method for Angular?

Tags: angular

i have these Variables:

```
 startLocations: Location[] = [];
  destLocations: Location[] = [];
  locationStartCtrl = new FormControl();
  locationDestCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredStartLocations: Observable<Location[]>;
  filteredDestLocations: Observable<Location[]>;
  selectedStartLocation: Location;
```

i want to simplify this Methods:

```
  private filterStartLocations() {
    this.filteredStartLocations = this.locationStartCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(location => location ? this._filterLocations(location, this.startLocations) : this.startLocations.slice())
    );
  }

 private filterDestLocations() {
    this.filteredDestLocations= this.locationDestCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(location => location ? this._filterLocations(location, this.destLocations ) : this.destLocations.slice())
    );
  }
```

I tried it with

```
  private filterDestLocations(getLocations: Location[], filterLocations: Observable<Location[]>, ctrl: FormControl) {
    filterLocations = ctrl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(location => location ? this._filterLocations(location, getLocations) : getLocations.slice())
    );
    return filterLocations;
 }
```

But if I try this one, it won´t work.It´s only because of the filterLocations parameter. Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: ok, so, is this java, or angular?

Comment: its angular whops sorry

Comment: why not extract the common code into a function? or what kind of "simplification" are you looking for?

Comment: If logic in both methods is similar then you can encapsulate this functions to pure ones. Then reuse pure function by passing them to the pipe operator.

Comment: I want to have one Method not 2 because they exatly the same methods except that the variables are different

Comment: @KarolTrybulec How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One way to simplify is following:**

```
private filterLocations(locations: Location[], ctrl: FormControl, isDest: boolean = false): void {
    const fLocation: Observable<Location[]> = ctrl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(location => location ? this._filterLocations(location, locations) : locations.slice();
    );

    if (!isDest) {
        this.filteredStartLocations = fLocation;
    } else {
        this.filteredDestLocations = fLocation;
    }
}
```

**Another way is this:**

```
private filterLocations(locations: Location[], ctrl: FormControl): void {
    return ctrl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(location => location ? this._filterLocations(location, locations) : locations.slice();
    );
}
```

And you would call the function like this:

```
this.filteredStartLocations = this.filterLocations(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private filterDestLocations(getLocations: Location[], flocations: Observable<Location[]>, ctrl: FormControl) {
    return ctrl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(location => location ? this.flocations(location, getLocations) : getLocations.slice())
    );
    return filterLocations;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work... there is not filterLocations where I save that

Comment: How are you using filterDestLocations function?

Comment: I use it in my html like https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples in *ngFor